# Broadcast- UNET Stack

Tags: unetstack

How do you write a code for Broadcast using Java Groovy on UnetStack?
Its basically where one node can broadcast the message to all the other nodes by checking whether all the nodes are free or not.

I wanted to write a code on unetstack for broadcast in groovy, but I keep getting all sorts of errors, semantic errors etc, is there anyone who's writteen anything similar to broadcast on groovy for unetstack?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any datagram transmission on Unetstack with `to` field set to 0 is a broadcast. Fairly straightforward to do. If you have a specific problem, please post your code snippet and exact error messages.